# Java reflection calling method "getDeclaredConstructors"

Tags: java, reflection

I didn't really know how to put the title of the question.
Basically i'm trying to do some tricky stuff with the java reflect api.
Here's what im trying to do:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String className = in.nextLine();
    Class c = Class.forName(className);
    Object myObj = c.newInstance();
    Method m = c.getMethod("getDeclaredConstructors");
    Object retn = m.invoke(myObj);
    System.out.println(retn);
    in.close();
}
}
```

I'm testing this with the input:
   java.lang.String
I always get as output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.String.getDeclaredConstructors()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1778)
    at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

I understand that the method "getDeclaredConstructors()" is from the class `Class.`

Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong here? What i was expecting was a list of the declared constructors for the class name i gave as input, in this case: `java.lang.String`

**EDIT:** I should have detailed more my problem.
I know that i could execute c.getDeclaredConstructors(), but thats not the case.

This is only a small part of the program i want to build.
In the final version, the user will provide as input a name of a class, say "java.lang.String" and then it will provide generic methods that he wishes to apply to that class.
So the user would enter "getDeclaredConstructors" and i would have to apply the method with that name to the class "java.lang.String".

Im only doing this to understand how exactly i can achive that.

Comment: Why are you double reflecting? You already have the `Class` object `c`. Just call `c.getDeclaredConstructors()` directly.

Comment: Because this is only a snippet of the final app im creating. In the final system, the user enters a name for a class, e.g, "java.lang.String", and then asks for general methods to execute on that class. So a user could enter as input: "method getDeclaredConstructors" and i would have to apply the method "getDeclaredConstructors" to the class the user previously entered. This is just to understand how can i do it

Answer (score 2):

`getMethod()` returns the methods of `String` (in this case), not of `Class`. `String` doesn't have such a method.

And why exactly would you want to call this method reflectively in the first place? It's a public API.

Comment: I guess i didn't detailed my problem enough, my bad. Could you please read my edit?

Comment: Re your edit, the only way the user would get to know the available methods would be if you told him, and you wouldn't tell him that `getDeclaredConstructors()` existed for `String.class`, because it doesn't, so you wouldn't retrieve it. In short the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you had a right problem but tested with a wrong method. Methods of java.lang.Class are accessed through the object of other classes. For this one, you can try access a method from java.lang.Object, like below,

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String className = in.nextLine();
Class c = Class.forName(className);
Object myObj = c.newInstance();
Method m = c.getMethod("hashCode");
Object retn = m.invoke(myObj);
System.out.println(retn);
in.close();
}
}
```

Hope this helps you.